# I would like to understand the use of the "reversed" property of TweenJS

Tags: createjs, tweenjs

I don't find any valid example for understand the use of "reversed" propertie in TweenJs. Could you send me a bit of code, explaining this issue? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The "reversed" property just runs the tween sequence in reverse. All positions are played in the reverse order as defined, and even the eases are applied in reverse ([docs](https://createjs.com/docs/tweenjs/classes/AbstractTween.html#property_reversed)).

For example, if you create a tween that animates the `x` position from 0 to 100, playing it reversed animates it from 100 to 0. If you apply a "quadOut" ease, it will slow down near the end, but in reverse it speeds up as it plays backwards.

Here is a quick example that shows two identical tweens, but one of them is reversed: https://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/98k0zvdx/

```
createjs.Tween.get(s, {loop:true})
    .to({x:300}, 3000, createjs.Ease.bounceOut);
createjs.Tween.get(s2, {loop:true, reversed:true}) // This one is reversed
    .to({x:300}, 3000, createjs.Ease.bounceOut);
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: And....why it doesn't work properly in the ANIMATE environnement? It's curious, but your example it´s ok in html page but it doesn't work inside animate API....

Comment: The likely reason is that Animate ships with an older version that doesn't support it. You could try replacing the TweenJS version in your export.